# In R, Error for No Boto3 to connect Athena even though Boto3 Installed

Tags: python, r, boto3, amazon-athena, pyathena

I am trying to connect to Athena from R. After setup 'RAthena' and connection, I got this error:

```
Error: Boto3 is not detected please install boto3 using either: `pip install boto3` in terminal or `install_boto()`.
            Alternatively `reticulate::use_python` or `reticulate::use_condaenv` will have to be used if boto3 is in another environment.
```

So by using `pip install`, I installed `boto3` in both Python 2 and Python 3.

```
Requirement already up-to-date: boto3 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (1.12.39)
```

```
Requirement already satisfied: boto3 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (1.12.39)
```

But in `R`, I am still having the same error. Then I tried using `install_boto()` in `R`.
It tells me to do as follow:

```
Installation complete. Please restart R.
```

Then I would stay in this `Restarting R session...` output forever and never see any note for successful restart.
And at the end, `R` still can't detect `boto3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

really sorry to hear you are having issue with the `RAthena` package. Can you let me know what version of the package you are running.

Have you tried setting which python you are using through `reticulate`? For example:

```
library(DBI)

# specifying python conda environment
reticulate::use_condaenv("RAthena")

# Or specifying python virtual enviroment
reticulate::use_virtualenv("RAthena")

con <- dbConnect(RAthena::athena())
```

Can you also check if `numpy` is installed, I remember `reticulate` can bind to python environments better if `numpy` is apart of it.

Alternatively you can use [`noctua`](https://github.com/DyfanJones/noctua). `noctua` works exactly the same as `RAthena` but instead of using python's `boto3` it uses R's `paws` package.

If you are still struggling I can raise this as an issue on Github. I thought I had resolved this issue by adding `numpy` to the installation function `install_boto`, however I am happy to re-open this issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough explanation. I did need to use `reticulate` method to proceed. And `python3 -m pip install some_module` worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Dyfan's answer, I was in a container and didn't want to mess with virtual environments, so this worked for me:

```
reticulate::use_python('/usr/bin/python3')
```

And that python installation was already endowed with boto3.